# How to send and receive user's location to database and use it in map [Android]

Tags: android, dictionary, location

I'm developing a tracking system between two users using android where both have their own android device, this application should work as follow:

the first user's android device has to discover its current location (latitude and longitude).
the user's location (latitude and longitude) has to be uploaded into a database periodically and continuously once the user's location is changed.
 the second user's android device retrieves these latitudes and longitude and then displays the first user's location on a googleMap based on them.

I can discover the user's current latitude and longitude for once easily and the database is prepared to receive them and everything is fine, but how to discover them once they changed and keep uploading them into the database continuously ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to  above comments as they perfectly gets user location and for sending location to database use firebase realtime database (you can try it for free) and like a chatting app send users location periodically and receive the same in others mobile by getting the Json from realtime database.
Moreover if you want to limit it between 2 users assign the user same topic"". For more information please deep dive into firebase.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overriden method called `onLocationChanged` in `LocationListener` which provides us latest Location whenever user place gets changed.

Reference: [LocationListener guidelines](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the same code of fetching current location in onLocation changed. That will automatically update the values every time when change is there in position.